# IE11 where are cookies really stored?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11

On Windows 7 or Windows 10, if I open IE and go to *Twitter.com* and log in clicking the Remember Me checkbox, log in and log out again, it does indeed Remember Me - my username is stored.

However, if I go into Internet Options → Browsing History → Settings → View Files there is no cookie visible there for *twitter.com* - there are only cookies for Microsoft sites (*eg: cookie:kim@ieonline.microsoft; cookie:kim@bing*)

I have searched the hard drive in other locations but cannot find any cookie from twitter on the filesystem. Can anyone tell me where the 3rd party cookie is stored?

Comment: they hang out around here in windows 7 C:\Users\THEUSERSNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies most of them anyway

Comment: Also here. C:\Users\THEUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low

Comment: Useful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/windows-7-internet-explorer-11-change-cookie/5c426f24-6611-459d-b656-34f4afd9679d?rtAction=1485178008305 I open folder 
***C:\Users\THEUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache***
and view ***Cookie:THEUSERNAME@localhost/***
If I open CMD and open folder ***C:\Users\THEUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache*** 
but no view cookie txt file.
I would like create _an scripting (batch file) for delete the cookie_  ***Cookie:THEUSERNAME@localhost/***

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time IE11 stores cookies in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies` or if you're using IE in protected mode, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low`.

But...

From IE10 and up, only the cookie itself is stored in the roaming directory and the instructions of what site they belong to and how they're to be used are stored in a database located at `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat`.
This file can be quite large (as far as databases used web browsers are concerned), so if you're using running Roaming Profiles on a network with hundreds of users and use some form or redirection or syncing to include this file, make sure your storage is capable.

Comment: This is only true for Windows 7.